# MySQL dump resulting in file of zero bytes

Tags: php, mysql

Why is this PHP script creating an SQL file that is empty (Zero bytes)?

```
<?php
$host ='HOSTNAME';
$user ='USERNAME';
$password ='PASSWORD';
$database ='DATABASE';
$filename =date('U').'.sql';

$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$host .' -u' .$user .' -p' .$password .' ' .$database .' > ' .$filename;

exec($command);
?>
```

This is a WordPress database on a 1&1 (IONOS) managed server. I've tried shell_exec instead of exec, but that doesn't work either. I've also checked safe_mode (it is off). I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the machine running this even have access to the `mysqldump` executable? Have you tried echoing out `$command` and if possible, run it yourself?

Comment: `exec()` supports 2 more arguments, one for output and one for error status. Catch and print them.